# How can I see images from usb_cam?

Tags: ros, camera, image-raw, image-view, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon.

I have usb_camera installed on my groovy raspbian.
I have done : rosparam set usb_cam/pixel_format yuyv and after that I wrote : rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node

I´m being given :

> usb_cam video_device set to [/dev/video0]

```
       usb_cam io_method set to [mmap]

       usb_cam image_width set to [640]

       usb_cam image_height set to [480]

       usb_cam pixel_format set to [yuyv]

       usb_cam auto_focus set to [0]

      10 frames/sec at 1353855178.185472348

      10 frames/sec at 1353855178.314173063

      9 frames/sec at 1353855178.849589157

      10 frames/sec at 1353855179.782349046

       ...
```

My rostopic list is the next :

/rosout

/rosout_agg

/usb_cam/camera_info

/usb_cam/image_raw

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressedDepth

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions

/usb_cam/image_raw/theora

/usb_cam/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions

/usb_cam/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates

What´s the next I have to do to be able to see captured images?

Thanks you so much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131121/how-can-i-see-images-from-usb_cam-?/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a screen connected (and graphical interface) it is easy:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw
```

Otherwise you have to have to look at the multiple machines page:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-19**:
Thanks for your answer.
I´m getting a poor frame rate this time I don´t know why : only 1 or 2 frames/sec.
I did it but with this message

Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display 10.1" What does it mean?
Here is the result : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11829245/IMG_20140219_235421.jpg

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-02-19**:
@4LV4R0 It should be a problem of Raspberry Pi instead of ROS. check this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=13773&p=205968

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-19**:
I was using xdrp with a remote desktop on windows. I think the missing message was because it. I get 15, 16 frames/sec but I can´t see the image correctly. Can it be because of the pixel_format wich may could not be supported? With mjpeg it´s horrible: only a few frames, not continous, black screen